# Reference Request: Video Lectures for Stochastic Processes

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

It  is  difficult to learn Stochastic Process  by self-reading. Can you provide some video lectures on Stochastic Process?

Comment: Have you tried searching Youtube? I see several videos there. Why don't they work?

Comment: @Thomas, actually I need a measure theoretic approach. so I've posted here to get a fine one.
I've viewed many of them

Comment: Maybe you can be a bit more specific then about what you are looking for.

Comment: @Thomas Who's the 'we' who aren't deaf? There very well might be deaf people reading this who appreciate his caps.

Comment: @QuinnCulver: I deleted my comment. The OP had used all caps in the title. This is by many people thought of as shouting. Even a person who might actually be deaf could/might consider this "shouting".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can look to the Open Course Ware areas for such videos (but this is not an easy topic and generally requires a lot of work to understand).

These typically come with video lectures, notes, homework, solutions, exams ... and are free.

For example:

- [*MIT Discrete Stochastic Processes*](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-262-discrete-stochastic-processes-spring-2011/index.htm)
- [*MIT Advanced Stochastic Processes*](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-070-advanced-stochastic-processes-fall-2005/index.htm)
- [*MIT Stochastic Processes, Detection, and Estimation*](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-432-stochastic-processes-detection-and-estimation-spring-2004/index.htm)
- [*MIT Search Results*](http://search.mit.edu/search?site=ocw&client=mit&getfields=%2a&output=xml_no_dtd&proxystylesheet=http%3A%2F%2Focw.mit.edu%2Fsearch%2Fgoogle-ocw.xsl&proxyreload=1&as_dt=i&oe=utf-8&departmentName=web&courseName=&q=stochastic+processes&btnG.x=-602&btnG.y=-271) for other examples of classes in these areas.

There are many other Open Course Ware programs internationally, but you can search those out.

I would also recommend going to your college library or searching MSE and your favorite book-site for book references and searching the web for introductory notes.

Comment: A very quick down vote..... This is a good answer! (+1)

Comment: And a very fast up vote. :-)

Comment: You are a great "reference-generating-resource"!

Comment: Do you keep lists/bibliographies in "endnotes" or similar programs?